# How to convert pixel to angle

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

i'm new to image processing..
I have a grace-scale pic in size 1024*768 represent in a numpy array.
I want to do some calculation form the middle of the pic (pix 511*383) with angles, how do i convert the pix position from x,y to angle?

for example: i want to sum all the pixels in 12 degree and divide them with all the pixels in 60 degree

BTW i'm using python and opencv

Comment: trygonometry: `tan(angle) = y/x`. Wikipedia: [Trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions)

Comment: `angle = math.degrees(math.atan(y/x))`

Comment: maybe it is easier to calculate all (x,y) which you have to get `for x in range(512): y = x * math.tan(math.radius(angle))`

Comment: Guys, realize that neither x or y is a distance from the camera. It is impossible to use trig to get an angle with only those specified.

Comment: @sahar, can you elaborate on the question a bit more? Like what do you mean by angle?

Comment: do yourself a favour and get the basics of maths right befor you get into image-processing. like you learn how to apply a bandaid long time befor you get to do your first surgery.  so what is it you want to do? what are "all the pixels in 60 degree"? all pixels on a 60 degree line from the central pixel? if so, where do you stop? at the image border or at a certain radius within the image boundaries?

Comment: @tpk the pic is from a rotating radar, x,y are the position of a pixel. i want to use azimuth to do some calculation in the image.

Comment: @sahar, So the origin(where the radar is) is at the center of the image? Can you confirm it? If yes, then to calculate the azimuth, you have to shift the `(x,y)`. This is because the origin of the image is at the top left corner.  Can you check the link to see if I got it right? https://photos.app.goo.gl/1RxmSKqLi73oSWbW7 If I recall it correctly, the radr gives the output as a sequence. Did you convert it into an image?

Comment: @tpk the (x,y) are ok, its converted to an image and i got the axes correctly. if i got the pic in the link right then yes i want all the pixel that the line of the 60 degree represent. just the line is not represent the 60 degree in azimuth look at this drawing: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ovG_PJ68R-8li00PtdbHiqHBOJbySaGG/view?usp=sharing)